# :root Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular

Мне нужно динамически применить некоторые CSS custom properties в :root{}
Как я могу это сделать? Заранее,спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:root` - это глобальная область видимости, поэтому нужно такое делать вручную:

```
import { Inject, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

class Component {
    constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document, private renderer: Renderer2) {
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.document.documentElement, 'background', 'red');
    }
}
```

А еще лучше вариант - это не писать стили вручную, а объявить просто класс в `styles.scss`:

```
:root {
    &.some-class {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

В компоненте можно делать `toggle` класса по определенному условию:

```
this.document.documentElement.classList.toggle('some-class');
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, пока ожидал придумал такой "костыль"                                                                    let element :HTMLElement = document.querySelector(":root") as HTMLElement;

Comment: @DanilSereda, в Angular нежелательно использовать нативное апи браузера типа `querySelector` и тд :)